# When to call flush_rewrite_rules in multisite setup

Tags: php, wordpress

The [official advice](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage) on flushing rewrite rules is on plugin activation and deactivation.

This advice does not work for multisite, where each site keeps its own cache of rewrite rules. Even if you called `flush_rewrite_rules` on every existing site during plugin activation, this would not catch new sites added in future.

When should `flush_rewrite_rules` be called from within a plugin to ensure all sites have the correct rules loaded on their first hit?